# Access to Stellar Expert Market Pair

Tags: transactions, assets

I am new to Stellar and I had a question whether the marker pairs on Stellar Expert are public for general consumption, or are many of these private connections? https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/market?type=fiat

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can add offers to the Stellar network. Once there is a valid buy and sell offer the Stellar Network will complete the transaction automatically.

So to answer your question, they are public for general consumption.